# a4j:status and richtabpanel issue

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am trying to use a4j:status along with richpaneltab. I have 3 tabs. When I user a4j:status in only one of the tabs then it is working fine. However if I add it for another tab then it throws a duplicate status id execption for "status".
I tried adding an id for a4j:status and also added forceid=true. But now, the a4j:status message and image is not getting displayed.
I aslo tried adding a4g:region around the below listed code for each tab. But again,a4j:status message and image is not getting displayed.

```
    <div align="center">
            <rich:modalPanel id="panel2" autosized="false" keepVisualState="false" style="text-align:center" width="315" height="100" >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="Processing Request...." style="color:green;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;"/>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:graphicImage value="/images/ajax/ajax-loader.gif" />
                    </h:column> 
                </h:panelGrid> 
            </rich:modalPanel>
            </div>

            <div align="center">

                <a4j:status onstart="javascript:Richfaces.showModalPanel('panel2');" onstop="#{rich:component('panel2')}.hide();" />

            </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "if I add it for another tab"? are you putting a a4j:status for each tab? It will be heplful if you post the whole code, including the rich:tabPanel code